# Probability of Jointly Uniform Distributed RV's

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Let $X, Y$ be jointly uniformly distributed random variables, with joint PDF:
>   $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{25\pi}\mathbf 1_{x^2 + y^2 \leq 25}$$
>   The question is to compute $P(|XY| \leq \sqrt{5})$, and $P(|X+Y| \leq 5)$.

I believe I have the second one correct, but for the first one I get an extremely complicated answer.

What I did was I drew the disk with radius $5$, and then drew the graph of $|XY| \leq \sqrt{5}$, and found the area that was overlapping between the two, and multiplied it by the joint PDF. But like I said, I got an extremely complicated answer, and was wondering if I was doing this correctly. If someone could help me out it would be appreciated.

The way I *attempted* to solve this was the following:

I found the area between the disk and the graph $|XY| \leq \sqrt5$ in the first quadrant by integration. Then I subtracted this from the area of the quarter circle in the first quadrant. This gave me the area that I required in the first quadrant. Then I multiplied that area by 4 to get the whole region, then I multiplied it by the joint PDF. I know there's no numbers here, but it came out to be really confusing and long, I just wanted someone to check on this and see if I was doing it correctly.

Comment: It might help if you showed your answer and how you calculated it by editing your question

Comment: I edited into it my thought process for the solution I came up with.

Comment: What is $R$ in the first equation?

Comment: I get $1-\dfrac{2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac25 \right)+\frac45 \log_e\left({\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}} \right)}{\pi} \approx 0.66096$ which seems similar to a simulation